# Addition of LCM

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I come across the sum $\sum_{1}^{n/2} \operatorname{LCM}(i,n)$

Is there any fast way to get the solution of this sum? Any ideas that we can apply other than euclidean algorithm to find the solution.

Comment: Why no one even answered or just gave info.I think question is good enough